# remove third-level navigation wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, navigationbar

We're using a theme that has responsive navigation... but it's pretty bad on the third-level. I'd like to remove that level completely on devices less that 768px wide.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this? All of the navigation elements seem to be converting to `<option>`... is there a way to tell it to only do this to top- and second-level navigation?

http://www.torontofamilytherapist.com/

Thank ya!

Comment: ...converting to < option > elements

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    display: none
  }
}
```

Should do it. You could also add that selector and declaration to a similar media query if you have one already.

Comment: Sadly, somewhere in the javascript (or something... haven't quite figure that out yet...) the menu is being converted to this:
<select class=“select-menu”>
<option value=“#”> Navigate to…</option>
<option value=“http://www.torontofamilytherpist.com/“ select=“selected”>Home</option>
<option value="http://www.torontofamilytherpist.com/services/counselling-services/“>-Counselling Services</option>
<option value="http://www.torontofamilytherpist.com/portfolio-view/individual-counseling/“>—Individual Counselling</option>
(etc…) How to get rid of the “Individual Counselling”? Painful, eh?

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty unconventional mobile menu. I do have an idea though. `option[value$="individual-conseling"] {
    display:none;
}` Put that in the same media query. It looks for an option element with a value that ends in 'individual-conseling' and applies the rule. Kind of hackish but deals with the weird menu.

Comment: Thanks ftairs - that's appreciated. I want to keep the code fluid so that if the menu changes, the display:none will still apply. Sounds like it's time to reach out to a dev!